# Facebook Platform error: "Object cannot be liked"

Tags: php, facebook

I'm working on a Facebook Application that generates wall posts.  In testing these posts, I've discovered that the Facebook Platform action of "liking" a post is failing.  The specific error message is

> **Object cannot be liked**
>   Unable to
>   like this object because it is not
>   accessible (it may have been removed
>   or you may no longer have permission
>   to see it).

Neither of the conditions suggested in the error are actually true.

- Googling for the error returns [zero results](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Object+cannot+be+liked%22)(!) (EDIT! Now returns a result - this question)
- Searching the Facebook bug repository returns [zero results](http://bugs.developers.facebook.com/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=Object+cannot+be+liked). (EDIT! Returns [one result](http://bugs.developers.facebook.com/show_bug.cgi?id=7540) now because I reported this bug)
- Searching the Facebook community forums yields [two posts](http://forum.developers.facebook.com/search.php?search_id=1120083989) neither of which address this specific issue.

These wall-to-wall posts are generated via [stream.publish](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.publish) using their PHP library. Here's a sample of the API call from my production code

```
$this->facebook->api_client->stream_publish(
    ''
  , array(
        'name'        => 'Sample Wall Post'
      , 'description' => 'Just a test description'
      , 'media'       => array(
          FbAppHelper::imageAttachment( 'path/to/image.gif', 'http://apps.facebook.com/' . FB_CANVAS_URI )
        )
    )
  , null
  , $facebookId
);
```

Any clues?

Comment: If the object is Facebook then I agree that the object cannot be liked.

Comment: @WP: Damn. You beat me to it :p What a funny error msg :)

Comment: This is such a hilarious error message. Wonder when it will first turn up on a T-Shirt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug for this issue has been closed.  No longer occurs

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=7540

Answer (score 1):

Hey, I know this doesn't help you, but I encountered a object which can't be "liked" too.  I got the same error message, and I think the "object" was generated within Facebook itself (not through a third party app).  It's something someone posted to my wall.

No clue why, but it just happens on that one message and it gives me the same error message you see.  Hope you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me, too, consistently for all the photos of one of my FB friends, when I click on "Like."

[Object cannot be liked]

Unable to like this object because it is not accessible (it may have been removed or you may no longer have permission to see it).

[Okay]

I also get a similar message when I try to add a comment:

[No Permission to Add Comment or Trying to Comment on Deleted Post]

Sorry you may not have permission to add this comment or the original post may have been deleted.

[Okay]